# Why option "Remove permissions if app isn't used" is not showing to my app in "Apps & notifications"

Tags: android, permissions

This problem happens on the android emulator 11, and on my smartphone. This option appears but is disabled and I can't switch.

How I can enable this option on the emulator and on my smartphone?

For google maps, this option appears and I can switch.

[image: The option looks like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer from the google team on the following link:

[Auto Revoke Permissions settings panel missing on some apps (Android 11 API/System)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172325509#comment6)

In case you can't see the link above, see print below

[image: Answered here]